# Why does strptime() behave differently on OSX and on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, macos, strptime

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  struct tm t;
  strptime("2015-08-13 12:00:00", "%F %T", &t);
  printf("t.tm_wday = %d\n", t.tm_wday);
  return 0;
}
```

Under OSX, this is what I obtain:

```
$ gcc test_strptime.c
$ ./a.out
t.tm_wday = 0
```

But on Linux, this is what I get:

```
$ gcc test_strptime.c
$ ./a.out
t.tm_wday = 4
```

Why is the bahaviour different? I would expect the day of the week to be well defined, given the data and the time of the day?

Comment: Is 4 the correct output? So the correct question is: why is the output on OSX wrong?

Comment: Yes, 4 (Thursday) is the correct/expected output.

Comment: Are the other fields of `t` correct ?

Comment: Most of them are, but `t.tm_yday` is also set to 0.

Comment: You're supposed to zero `t`before use, and you're supposed to check the return code of strptime. (%F is not in POSIX AFAICT)

Comment: @Mat The [official reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) *mentions* `F` but doesn't actually list it. It's a little ambiguous I think.

Comment: @Joachim: yes, that's a bit strange. (I was looking at an older version where it isn't even mentioned.)

Comment: @nos I added a check to the return value of strptime() and it returns a pointer to 0x0. (NOT a NULL pointer)

Comment: @lindelof It returns a pointer to the terminator, meaning it parsed the whole string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux (glibc) and OS X implementations of `strptime` are different. From the [OS X man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strptime.3.html):

> If the format string does not contain enough conversion specifications to completely specify the
>        resulting `struct tm`, the unspecified members of tm are left untouched. For example, if format is
>        ``%H:%M:%S'', only `tm_hour`, `tm_sec` and `tm_min` will be modified.

Compared with [glibc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html):

> The glibc implementation does not touch those fields which are not explicitly specified, except that it recomputes the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` field if any of the year, month, or day elements changed.

So, you could say it's working as documented.

Comment: Yes, but with "%F %T" the exact date _is_ specified, And the OS X man pages state that the %F specifier exists.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, but unlike on linux it doesn't recompute/set tm_wday - I believe none of the BSD based system does. You would have to use any of the %a, %A, %u, %w specifiers to set it.