# Why does the following simple Python 3 strptime() code run on OSX but not on Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code to read and validate an ISO8601 format date works as expected on python 3.7.4 OSX. It raises an error on Linux

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct 14 2019, 21:22:53) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime('2019-11-05T00:00:00Z', format_string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2019-11-05T00:00:00Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

Under OSX:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:15:00) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime('2019-11-05T00:00:00Z', format_string)
>>> print(d)
2019-11-05 00:00:00+00:00
```

I looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984002/why-does-strptime-behave-differently-on-osx-and-on-linux) which relates to C library calls, but surely Python should be portable?

The two distros I have tried (Red Hat and EC2 Linux) both have 3.6.8 from `yum` and both give the error. Surely it can't be a version difference?

Comment: always use the generic [python] tag for all python questions. Use version-specific tags at your discretion.

Comment: you have lower 'z' at the end of your format string - the input string has a capital 'Z'...

Comment: This could be a python version issue or something specific to one particular Linux distro. Fedora 31 with Python 3.7.5, for example, works the same way as your macOS example. As for "Python should be portable?", yeah it should. But in many cases, python was designed to be a thin wrapper over the OS libc APIs. Sometimes that leaks through.

Comment: Thank you .. the input string capital Z is deliberate, it denotes "UTC".

There is also odd Linux behavior if we use `+0000` or `+00:00` .. the first is accepted, the second one is not. But print() gives the second form back out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this OSX in Python 3.6.8 and Python 3.7.4 Conda environments. It does seem to be a discrepancy between the Python versions.

This is because support for the usage of `'Z'` at the end of datetime  formatted strings was added in Python 3.7. `'Z'`is an alias for a UTC offset of "+00:00", and support for colons separators in UTC offsets was not added to the `'%z'` directive until Python 3.7.

For a solution that will work with both Python 3.6 and 3.7, instead of using `'Z'`, use `'+0000'` so the datetime string becomes `'2019-11-05T00:00:00+0000'`.

```
format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
d = datetime.strptime('2019-11-05T00:00:00+0000', format_string)
```

will work in both versions.

For further reference, check [the Python 3.7 datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Ah .. now I see it

Changed in version 3.7: When the %z directive is provided to the strptime() method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds. For example, '+01:00:00' will be parsed as an offset of one hour. In addition, providing 'Z' is identical to '+00:00'.

Comment: I've attached a function below that attempts conversion, and uses exception handling to catch the pre-3.7 conversion failures, comments welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround to different behaviours seen. This function is intended to be used with `argparse` hence the final line.

```
def iso8601_tzoffset(timestamp):
    """
    Validate time string, which includes Seconds and (optional) timezone offset.
    Beautiful idea made ugly by strptime() timzone offset syntax varying between Python 3.6 and 3.7?
    :param timestamp: str
    :return: datetime
    """
    format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
    try:
        d = datetime.strptime(timestamp, format_string)
        return d
    except ValueError as e:
        # We want to accept "Z", but strptime doesn't on all platforms, so fix it up here
        if timestamp.endswith('Z'):
            timestamp = timestamp.rstrip('Z') + '+0000'
        else:
            # We want to accept timezone HH:MM with separator, but strptime <3.7 requires HHMM, fix it up here
            sep = max(timestamp.rfind('+'), timestamp.rfind('-'))
            if sep < 0:
                raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(e)
            else:
                tz = timestamp[sep:]
                ymdhms = timestamp[:sep]
                tz = tz.replace(':', '')
                timestamp = ymdhms + tz
        try:
            d = datetime.strptime(timestamp, format_string)
            return d
        except:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(e)
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution to me. Very Pythonic of you to ask for forgiveness rather than permission (trying to `strptime` it before cleaning it up). Thank you for sharing. Another way to do it is with regular expressions, which I can share if you want.